Change input text color when auto filled is not working
when i auto fill the input data the input text color is black, i want to change it because it looks horrible on dark background, i traced the color properties on input and found one color property that is applied on selector input:-internal-autofill-selected which has property color:fieldtext, i changed that but it also doesn't work, isn't there a way to change it ?
// this is for the background when the input gets auto filled, setting color here doesn't work
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}

// found this class when inspecting the color property applied, changed it, but doesn't work
input:-internal-autofill-selected {
  color: #fff !important;
}

